# Missing options on database connection in ArcCatalog

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog

I have 2 databases on the same server. I can add connections to them both without a hitch in ArcCatalog (or catalog in ArcMap). The problem is that I seem to be losing some options when right clicking one of the database connections. Here is the first connection:

[image]

and here is the second:

[image]

As you can see, on my second connection, I do not have the option for "new", "import", or "export". Another user with seemingly identical permissions still has the options when they right click, so it only seems to be affecting me and only with this one database connection. How do I regain the ability to select these options? Also, I am on 10.1 for everything.

Comment: are the permissions the same for each?

Comment: Yes, from everything I can tell. The docs seem to act as if these options should always be there, so I am pretty perplexed.

Comment: hmm. those options seem to be something available to a user with write access. but since you say you have the same permissions for both connections, I'm not sure :/

Comment: Suppose they were different, I can create tables and do whatever I want to in SQL Server Management Studio. What sort of permissions should I be looking for?

Comment: The first one gives you the option to Connect to the database while the second gives you the option to disconnect.  Perhaps because you're not connected to the first one could be the reason.

Comment: @Fetzer- Good catch, but it makes no difference. I have updated the screen shot to show the menu when connected. I suppose it would be a bit odd anyway if I could only import/export when I was NOT connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I had accidentally set up my EDN license temporarily for ArcMap Basic license. Once I returned to an advanced license, everything returned to normal. I could import/export when SDE was not enabled, but since Basic does not allow SDE connections, for those DBs everything was disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The first one looks like a DATABASE connection, using a user that is not SDE.  The other looks like a GEODATABASE connection.

The difference being that in the first connection, no ArcSDE schema has been installed/setup in the database. The second connection is to a database where the ArcSDE schema is installed/setup.

If you connect to the sde user, using the first conenction's instance and database properties, that "Enable Geodatabase" button should enable.  Clicking it should start a GP tool that will allow you to setup that server as a Geodatabase.  After running that tool, the menus should be the same.

Database help topic: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_working_with_databases_in_ArcGIS/019v00000008000000/

Geodatabase help topic:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_geodatabase/003n00000001000000/